# Are there performance implications to creating a Thread and never starting it?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I'm working on an existing Java codebase which has an object that extends `Thread`, and also contains a number of other properties and methods that pertain to the operation of the thread itself. In former versions of the codebase, the thread was always an actual, heavyweight `Thread` that was started with `Thread.start`, waited for with `Thread.join`, and the like.

I'm currently refactoring the codebase, and in the present version, the object's `Thread` functionality is not always needed (but the object itself is, due to the other functionality contained in the object; in many cases, it's usable even when the thread itself is not running). So there are situations in which the application creates these objects (which extend `Thread`) and never calls `.start()` on them, purely using them for their other properties and methods.

In the future, the application may need to create many more of these objects than previously, to the point where I potentially need to worry about performance. Obviously, creating and starting a large number of actual threads would be a performance nightmare. Does the same thing apply to `Thread` objects that are never started? That is, are any operating system resources, or large Java resources, required purely to create a `Thread`? Or are the resources used only when the `Thread` is actually `.start`ed, making unstarted `Thread` objects safe to use in quantity? It would be possible to refactor the code to split the non-threading-related functionality into a separate function, but I don't want to do a large refactoring if it's entirely pointless to do so.

I've attempted to determine the answer to this with a few web searches, but it's hard to aim the query because search engines can't normally distinguish a `Thread` object from an actual Java thread.

Comment: I don't know if merely instantiating the object already allocates memory for the thread's stack, but why would you still inherit Thread if it's not a thread?

Comment: *"but the object itself is usable even when the thread itself is not running"* — That seems to me like a poor design. I think you should separate some functionality and place it somewhere else.

Comment: the only side-effect will be blowing up of entries in `ThreadLocal`s

Comment: @MauricePerry: it does some bookkeeping that can happen either synchronously or asynchronously. If it's doing it asynchronously, a thread's receiving commands to run via an InputStream; if it's being done synchronously, it can be done via method calls directly to the object so the thread isn't needed. Back when the object was created, it was always used asynchronously so making the object a Thread made sense; refactoring the code to support the synchronous case made it make a bit less sense, and I'm trying to work out how much effort needs to be spent on refactoring it further.

Comment: Unless the objects have a lot of fields, I would assume you can have millions of these without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create about 1.5 million of these objects per GB of memory.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            List<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<>();
            while (true) {
                threads.add(new Thread());
                if (++count % 10000 == 0)
                    System.out.println(count);
            }
        } catch (Error e) {
            System.out.println("Got " + e + " after " + count + " threads");
        }
    }
}
```

using `-Xms1g -Xmx1g` for Oracle Java 8, the process grinds to halt at around

```
1 GB - 1780000
2 GB - 3560000
6 GB - 10690000
```

The object uses a bit more than you might expect from reading the source code, but it's still about 600 bytes each.

NOTE: Throwable also use more memory than you might expect by reading the Java source. It can be 500 - 2000 bytes more depending on the size of the stack at the time it was created.

Answer (score 4):

You could implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`.

```
public class MyRunnableClass implements Runnable {

    // Your stuff...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Thread-related stuff...
    }

}
```

Whenever you need to run your `Object` to behave as a `Thread`, simply use:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnableClass());
t.start();
```

Comment: Or use a lambda expression, if you don't directly need properties within the object: `Runnable r = () -> doSomeWork();`. Trigger its running by calling `new Thread(r).start()`.

Answer (score 2):

As the others have pointed out: performance isn't a problem here.

I would focus much more on the "good design" approach. It simply doesn't make (much, any?) sense to extend Thread when you do not intend to ever invoke `start()`. And you see: you write code to communicate your intentions.

Extending Thread without using it as thread, that only communicates confusion. Every new future reader of your code will wonder "why is that"?

Therefore, focus on getting to a straight forward design. And I would go one step further: don't just turn to *Runnable*, and continuing to use threads. Instead: learn about ExecutorServices, and how to submit tasks, and Futures, and all that.

"Bare iron" Threads (and Runnables) are like 20 year old concepts. Java has better things to offer by now. So, if you are really serious about improving your code base: look into these new abstraction concepts to figure where they would make sense to be used.